# How to use 2 diffrent keypresses to move 2 diffrent shapes at once in python turtle

Tags: python

What im trying to do here is that if 'w' key pressed and 'Up' key pressed both player1 and player2 go up.
Right now, if you press both of them, only the one you pressed first will go up.
Of curse I still want that if only one of the keys get pressed, only the turtle that connect to him move.
How can I do that?

That's my Code:

```
import turtle
import random

turtle.screensize(1000,1000)
turtle.bgcolor("black")

ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.color("orange")
ball.shape("circle")
ball.shapesize(1.2)
ball.speed(3)
ball.penup()

player1 = turtle.Turtle()
player1.color("blue")
player1.shape("arrow")
player1.shapesize(5)
player1.speed(3)
player1.penup()
player1.setpos(350,0)

player2 = turtle.Turtle()
player2.color("cyan")
player2.shape("arrow")
player2.shapesize(5)
player2.speed(3)
player2.penup()
player2.setheading(180)
player2.setpos(-350,0)

player1y = 0
player2y = 0

def player1up():
    global player1y
    player1y += 12
    player1.goto(350,player1y)

def player1down():
    global player1y
    player1y -= 12
    player1.goto(350,player1y)

def player2up():
    global player2y
    player2y += 12
    player2.goto(-350,player2y)

def player2down():
    global player2y
    player2y -= 12
    player2.goto(-350,player2y)




turtle.listen()
turtle.onkeypress(player1up, 'Up')
turtle.onkeypress(player1down, 'Down')
turtle.onkeypress(player2up, 'w')
turtle.onkeypress(player2down, 's')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is what is known as [Game Loop](https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html).
Your code is working perfectly, but you application is exiting after the first render. So, to keep it rendering frames you need to keep your application alive, running. To do so you can do something like this:

```
import turtle

#set up the screen
app = turtle.Screen()
app.title("Your app")
app.bgcolor("black")
app.setup(width=1000, height=1000)
app.tracer(0)

ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.color("orange")
ball.shape("circle")
ball.shapesize(1.2)
ball.speed(3)
ball.penup()

player1 = turtle.Turtle()
player1.color("blue")
player1.shape("arrow")
player1.shapesize(5)
player1.speed(3)
player1.penup()
player1.setpos(350,0)

player2 = turtle.Turtle()
player2.color("cyan")
player2.shape("arrow")
player2.shapesize(5)
player2.speed(3)
player2.penup()
player2.setheading(180)
player2.setpos(-350,0)

player1y = 0
player2y = 0

def player1up():
    global player1y
    player1y += 12
    player1.goto(350,player1y)

def player1down():
    global player1y
    player1y -= 12
    player1.goto(350,player1y)

def player2up():
    global player2y
    player2y += 12
    player2.goto(-350,player2y)

def player2down():
    global player2y
    player2y -= 12
    player2.goto(-350,player2y)


turtle.listen()
turtle.onkeypress(player1up, 'Up')
turtle.onkeypress(player1down, 'Down')

turtle.onkeypress(player2up, 'w')
turtle.onkeypress(player2down, 's')

while True:
    app.update()
```

Basically, get the instance of the Screen, and call the update() method inside a while True loop, which will maintain your app running.

And all the code you have written is working as you expected.

[Here](https://www.edureka.co/blog/python-turtle-module/) is a little tutorial of another game made with the Turtle package. I believe it's not what you want to do but it could help as a guide.